# Find Item in List<T> That Threw Exception

Tags: c#

I have inherited a WCF web service application that requires to have much better error tracking. What we do is query data from one system (AcuODBC), and send that data to another system (Salesforce). This query will return 10's of thousands of complex objects as a `List<T>`. We then process this `List<T>` in batches of 200 records at a time to map the fields to another object type, then send that batch to Salesforce. After this is completed, the next batch starts. Here's a brief example:

```
int intStart = 0, intEnd = 200;
//done in a loop, snipped for brevity
var leases = from i in trleases.GetAllLeases(branch).Skip(intStart).Take(intEnd)
                       select new sforceObject.SFDC_Lease() {
                              LeaseNumber = i.LeaseNumber.ToString(),
                              AccountNumber = i.LeaseCustomer,
                              Branch = i.Branch 
                       (...)//about 150 properties

//do stuff with list and increment to next batch
intStart += 200;
```

However, the problem is if one object has a bad field mapping (Invalid Cast Exception), I would like to print out the object that failed to a log.

### Question

Is there any way I can decipher which object of the 200 threw the exception? I *could* forgo the batch concept that was given to me, but I'd rather avoid that if possible for performance reasons.

Comment: Not in the context of a LINQ query. If an exception is thrown when generating the collection, the collection doesn't get generated at all. If you wanted to know which threw, you would have to loop through manually adding the objects to a list, checking for exceptions as you go.

Comment: @JeffMercado That's what I was afraid of. I was hoping there would be a way to flag it, even in a property. Then query the batch where the flag was thrown.

Comment: "//about 150 properties" ouch, there's got to be another way...

Comment: @Verdolino With the architecture/schema that was put in place in AcuODBC (which is where the company keeps all their data - similar to a csv file), the 159 (actual number) fields is unfortunately necessary.

Comment: One option you might have is to create a generic passthrough function that takes in some value and returns it, but logging it as it goes through. At least  that way, you can set additional parameters to help identify what's being set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should accomplish what you are looking for with very minor code changes:

```
int intStart = 0, intEnd = 200, count = 0;
List<SDFC_Lease> leases = new List<SDFC_Lease>();
//done in a loop, snipped for brevity
foreach(var i in trleases.GetAllLeases(branch).Skip(intStart).Take(intEnd)) {
    try {
        count++;
        leases.Add(new sforceObject.SFDC_Lease() {
                              LeaseNumber = i.LeaseNumber.ToString(),
                              AccountNumber = i.LeaseCustomer,
                              Branch = i.Branch 
                       (...)//about 150 properties);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // you now have you culprit either as 'i' or from the index 'count'
    }    
}
//do stuff with 'leases' and increment to next batch
intStart += 200;
```

Comment: Pretty sure this will work. Probably didn't think of it because it's so simple ;). Implementing now and will test!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you. :) ♥

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use a flag in each set method of the properties of the class SFDC_Lease, and use a static property for this like:

```
public class SFDC_Lease
{
    public static string LastPropertySetted;
    public string LeaseNumber
    {
        get;
        set
        {
           LastPropertySetted = "LeaseNumber";
           LeaseNumber = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Plz, feel free to improve this design.